# How to remove elements from a 3D array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to remove first element from the every 1D array in the 1st, 2nd and 5th column.
The 3D array looks like

```
       1st col              2nd col                       3rd col                  4th col                  5th col
[
[[0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
]
```

Desired 3D array should look like

```
       1st col              2nd col                       3rd col                  4th col                  5th col

[
[[ 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 5], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 
[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 
[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 
[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 
[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
]
```

I am not sure what is best way to do this in ruby.

Comment: When you give an example, you should 1) pare it down to smallest size necessary to make your point (e.g, could you not have, say, 4 4x4 blocks?); 2) assign each input to a variable (e.g., `arr = [[[0,0...]`) so readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without have to define them. If I understand your question correctly,  all the elements you are removing are zeroes, which makes it difficult to understand the question from the example.

Comment: Cary Swoveland, I will make sure to simply my questions from next time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
array.map do |row_of_column_arrays| 
  row_of_column_arrays.each_with_index.map do |column_arr, index| 
    [0, 1, 4].include?(index) ? column_arr[1..-1] : column_arr
  end
end
```

Bottom-up, your array is made out of the following dimensions:

(1) Cell

(2) Column Array (e.g. `[0,0,0,2,3,0,0,5]`)

(3) Row of Column Array (e.g. the first row in your question)

(4) Array of Rows of Column Array (this is the value residing in `array`.

So, the first `map` is applied on #4 and goes over each Row of Column Arrays (3). For each of this we run the second `map` method, which goes over each Column Array (2). We simply return from that block that particular Column Array without the first element, if we are dealing with indices 0, 1, and 4 (corresponding to 1st, 2nd and 5th columns):

```
[0,0,0,2,3,0,0,5][1..-1]
# => [0,0,2,3,0,0,5]
```

Comment: That works but it removes element from every single column. I just need to remove the 1st element from 1st,2nd and 5th column.

Comment: Thanks AmitA. This solution works perfectly.

Comment: That's perhaps not the best reason to select an answer. Asking for the greenie wrankles.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do the following, where `arr` is your array:

```
arr_cpy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(arr))
[0,1,4].each { |i| arr_cpy[i] = arr_cpy[i].transpose[1..-1].transpose }
arr_cpy
```

I've used [Marshal#dump](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [Marshal#load](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load) to make a ["deep copy"](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/deepcopy.htm) of `arr`, so that `arr` will not be altered ("mutated"). If you wish to mutate `arr`, simply skip that step and change `arr_cpy` to `arr` in the second line.